# How can I use cin only once?

Tags: c++

I want to get multiple numbers from the user, in one line, and store it in a vector. This is how I am doing it:

```
vector<int> numbers;
int x;
while (cin >> x)
    numbers.push_back(x);
```

However, after entering my numbers and pressing enter, like so:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

It puts the numbers in the vector, and then awaits more input, meaning I have to enter `Ctrl+Z` to exit the loop. How do I automatically exit the loop after getting the one line of integers, so that I don't have to enter `Ctrl+Z`?

Comment: do you press enter after each of numbers or this is only a one line?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak It's a one line

Comment: Read a line of input (`getline`) into a `string` and then use a string stream to convert the data from the string into numbers.

Comment: If you want to read it like that then read the string with `getline`, then you've got to `split` on `' '`. I C++ doesn't have one you can easily write your own.

Comment: One answer (in Linux) is to press `Ctrl-D` (end of file) rather than `Ctrl-Z`.

Comment: It seems to me you need a way to tell your program you have input all your numbers. You could ask how many to input at the beginning or you could have a special value (like a blank line?) to indicate the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be using a string stream :

```
#include <sstream>
//....

std::string str;
std::getline( std::cin, str ); // Get entire line as string
std::istringstream ss(str);

while ( ss >> x ) // Now grab the integers
    numbers.push_back(x);
```

To validate the input, after loop you can do:

```
if( !ss.eof() )
{
   // Invalid Input, throw exception, etc
}
```

Comment: Why `std::stringstream`, rather than `std::istringstream`?  (I can't remember ever having used an `std::stringstream`.)

Comment: Also: I've do something to verify the format; as it is, if a line contains `"1 2 x 4"`, the code will parse the 1 and the 2, then stop without indicating an error.  (Checking that `ss.eof()` is true _after_ the loop would be sufficient.)

Comment: @JamesKanze 1) Used `std::istringstream`, I sometime blindly use `std::stringstream` for both input and output operation probably analogous to `std::fstream` 2) Added the check, thanks

Comment: FWIW: I don't think I've ever used `std::fstream` either.  (Generally, when I'm both reading and writing a stream, I'll use the native functions: `open`, `read`, `write`, `lseek` and `close`, or their equivalents in Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (std::cin.peek() != '\n') {
    std::cin >> x;
    numbers.push_back(x);
}
```

**update**

```
while (std::cin.peek() != '\n') {
    std::cin >> x;
    numbers.push_back(x);

    // workaround for problem from comment
    int tmp;
    while (!isdigit(tmp = std::cin.peek()) && tmp != '\n') {
      std::cin.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as well as POW's solution - any spaces/tabs after the last number and before the newline breaks it, and it gets stuck in a loop if the `std::cin >> x` conversion fails (e.g. some text on the line).

Comment: @flaggers: flags aren't intended to be used for correctness of code issues.

Comment: Both of these "solutions" are seriously broken, since they use the results of `std::cin >> x` without testing whether the input worked.

Comment: I know, it just to show how to fill vector. Testing input is other question.